# API HTTP client returning data

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I am working on this helper method that will call an API using the body section. I am passing in the url and data in the model. Then I SerializeObject the model, but I am not sure what to return I get the error message about the `response.Content` is not found.

```
 public static async System.Threading.Tasks.Task<HttpResponse> HttpClientHandlerAsync(string url, object model)
    {
        var fullUrl = apiUrl + url;
        
        var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(model);
        var data = new StringContent(json, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
        Client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Accept", "*/*");
        Client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization
                     = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", "token");
        var response = await Client.PostAsync(fullUrl, data);

        return response;
        
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add await in front of your

```
await Client.PostAsync(fullUrl, data);
```

Because you're trying to get content of Task

Comment: Yes you can, but for that you have to change your method signature, but what exactly are you trying to achieve here?

Answer (score 0):

> I am not sure what to return I get the error message about the response.Content is not found.

Set a breakpoint and hover over the response to see the status code. You could have a 500 server error, authentication error etc.

Furthermore

```
using (var client = new HttpClient())
```

Do not do this. It doesn't work the way you think it does, it will starve your connection pool and eventually throw an exception. You need to define the HttpClient somewhere and continue to reuse the same instance.

Further reading if you care https://aspnetmonsters.com/2016/08/2016-08-27-httpclientwrong/

Comment: Thanks but I am still not sure what to return? Is it an HttpResponse I get the convert type tasks.task<system.net.http.HttpResponseMessage> to system.web.HttpResponse

Comment: If your goal is to consume data from some web api, you read the content and put it into a custom model class. If it's JSON coming back you could make a model decorated with JSONProperty then use JsonConvert.Deserialize<MyCustomModelClass>();, then your return type from the method would be the custom model class. Google for json.net for examples.